# how to query table based on keyvaluepair where key is an integer and value is a list of integers

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

So, I have a table that has 3 things: a primary key, table_id, foreignkey_id and doctor_id.
- table_id refers to a table with a certain number.
- foreignkey_id refers to primary key within that table.
- doctor_id refers to a primary key in doctor table
Now, the user will select which tables he wants to use and which items in that table he wants. I need all the doctor_id's that match the combinations.

```
CREATE TABLE tConfidentiality(
    confidentiality_id serial primary key,
    table_id integer not null,
    doctor_id integer not null,
    foreignkey_id integer not null,
    constraint un_confidentiality unique(table_id, doctor_id, foreignkey_id)
);
INSERT INTO tConfidentiality(table_id, doctor_id, foreignkey_id) values(10, 100, 1000);
INSERT INTO tConfidentiality(table_id, doctor_id, foreignkey_id) values(10, 100, 2800);
INSERT INTO tConfidentiality(table_id, doctor_id, foreignkey_id) values(40, 100, 2000);
INSERT INTO tConfidentiality(table_id, doctor_id, foreignkey_id) values(80, 110, 2500);
INSERT INTO tConfidentiality(table_id, doctor_id, foreignkey_id) values(90, 120, 2800);
```

Query: The values have to be parameterized

All doctor_id in table 10 with `foreignkey_id` 1000 & 2800 and table 40 with `foreignkey_id` 2000

Expected result: 100

Don't expect you to write the entire thing, just point me in the right direction and I'll take it from there.

Comment: What if there was no row for table 40? Do you still want doctor_id 100 then? Do the rows need to match the list of foreign keys **exactly**? What if there is another row for table_id = 10 with e.g. foreignkey_id = 5000? Should doctor_id = 100 still be returned?

Comment: As long as the doctor is present in at least one table+foreign key match, he should get in the result.

Comment: And what about the list of foreign keys? Is that an "at least those" or an "exactly those" condition?

Comment: If the table_id contains 100  and list for 100 is 1200 and 1000, the result should be 10. If the table_id contains 100, and list for 100 contains 1000, 2800; result should also be 10. If the table_id is 100 but foreign key is 1500, result should be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to collect the foreign key ids for each table_id and then check if the contain at least those that you are looking for. In Postgres this can be done by aggregating them into an array:

```
select distinct doctor_id
from tConfidentiality
group by doctor_id, table_id
having table_id = 10 and array_agg(distinct foreignkey_id) @> array[1000,2800]
    or table_id = 40 and array_agg(distinct foreignkey_id) @> array[2000];
```

online example: https://rextester.com/NHE4869

Answer (score 1):

based on you sample you could use a join between the same table

```
select  doctor_id 
from  tConfidentiality t1
inner join tConfidentiality t2 on t1.doctor_id = t2.doctor_id
where t1.table_id = 10  AND t1.foreignkey_id IN (1000,2800  )
AND t2.table_id = 40 and t2.foreignkey_id = 2000
```

Comment: the amount of table_id's is variable, could be 1, could be 2, could be 10 or even 20. So I prefer not to go this way.

Comment: i can juts answer  at the question you post ...  ..  .based on yur question and your sample  this should work ..  for variable condtion  you should eval a procedural approach or build dinamic sql  ..

Comment: This will also return doctors (for table 10) where only one of the foreign_key IDs is assigned.